# set input value as the user is typing

Tags: jquery

**I have 1 input field.**

```
<input id="post_remote_posted_url" type="text" size="30" name="post[remote_posted_url]">
```

**How can I go filling the value from this field input when I go typing or writing inside this field?**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you need?  You've asked for the input to be filled when you're typing in it, which is what it already does.  Do you want the value to populate a different field?

Comment: I dont find any example :(. I want that when user its typing inside input field the attribute `value=""` from this field going filling with the text that user go writing.

Comment: For me this field its not filled when you go writing inside. I can see in firebug that this value is not changed.

Comment: Is this of any importance? The current value is always available, you can access it with `input.value`. The HTML source or even DOM view will only show the *initial* value though.

Comment: This is so incredibly pointless. The text within the input is stored in the `value` **property**, which shouldn't be confused with the `value` attribute; storing the value in the attribute serves absolutely no purpose unless you're intending to use an incorrect method to get the input's value back out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean like that: http://jsfiddle.net/6MurG/

```
$("#post_remote_posted_url")​.keyup(function(){
       $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
    })​
```